# Why should we choose to go for a smaller motor (4.5 kW vs 6 kW) for go-cart?

Tags: motor, lithium-ion, brushless-dc-motor, mechanical, electro-mechanical

We are thinking of using a 4.5 kW motor and not a 6 kW one. Due to some constraints and rules, the maximum power a motor can have is 6 kW. So why is it recommended to use a smaller motor? And does it have any performance benefits or drawbacks?

Comment: A smaller motor will, well, be smaller and use less power (at maximum load). Whether that is a good thing, will largely depend on your use case. What are you powering with the motor?

Comment: There is some context missing from this question.

Comment: I would think for the ability to minimize load regulated disturbances a bigger motor is better with ability to maintain speed with torque load variations. But if the mass is important, then a bigger power to weight ratio is considered.

Comment: We are powering a go kart.

Comment: You want 'kW' (kilowatt), not 'KW' (kelvin-watt). Who is recommending a smaller motor? It will be a bit lighter but obviously only give you 75% power and acceleration.

Comment: It is well known that the mass of the batteries for arial flight to power motor-blades cannot exceed the 30 minute practical limit.  Likewise EV-s  have a limited range depending on the stored energy and demands from loss in efficiency with rapid acceleration.  So additional mass of energy and power drive must consider usage. One ought to consider a motor that provides constant torque over a wide range in speed without a transmission such as switched reluctance motors with V/F brushless torque and speed control.

Comment: Is that 4.5/6 kW a 'rated' power, or do the rules limit the power the electronics deliver to the motor? You can generally overdrive a motor for a few seconds at the cost of efficiency if you want burst performance, eg for overtaking, for which a lighter motor will be beneficial. What are the features that will enable you win? Battery endurance? Top speed? Overtaking performance? How about you engineer the cart so it can take both, and see what results each gets you.

Comment: Yes it is Rated Power. The Peak Power for the 4.5kW motor is 6 kW.

Comment: The ESC must be capable of > 10x the motor rated current if you plan on max power on start.

Comment: Hmmmm the max capabilities of the motor will change with max power rating, but objectively, if both motors can achieve the maximum power levels required, the better motor is the one sized to be more efficient over the bulk of operating conditions.  This is what Tony's pointing out.  The newest electric car motors I've seen videos on use combination permanent magnet and reluctance cores to get the efficiency advantages of both over a wider speed range for example.